# Installed Maven, but mvn -version is not recognized. Works when I use %M2_HOME%\bin\mvn -version

Tags: maven

I downloaded and unzipped the Maven directory on my C: drive.

Set **M2_HOME : C:\opt\apache-maven-3.6.3** in the environment variable.

I have added  **%M2_HOME%\bin** to the path.

But when I try to run mvn -version, it says "mvn" is not recognized.

But when I run **%M2_HOME%\bin\mvn -version** it works fine.

Comment: Probably your path is defined before `M2_HOME`. Try adding the full path instead or make sure `M2_HOME` is defined before `PATH`.

Comment: Remove `M2_HOME` only add the location of the bin directory into the `PATH` variable. After you have changed the environment close the all consoles and reopen the console.

Comment: @kriegaex it worked. I added the full path and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you. After adding the full path it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to reload your console / command line window - IFAIK the %PATH% variable is read only once - when the console window is opened